# Filter model assigned to user , ManyToManyField - Django

Tags: python, django

new to django and I am finding it hard to know what to search and what questions to ask sooo....here it goes...

I have a model named Obiectiv to which I have assigned users in the admin panel using manytomanyfield.

models.py:

```
class Obiectiv(models.Model):
    numeObiectiv = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=COLOR_CHOICES, default='green')
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I want that when the user is logged in, he is able to see only the models that have been assigned to him:

views.py

```
@login_required
def home(request):   
    obiective  = Obiectiv.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', context={"obiective":obiective})
```

With the code in the views.py it display all the Obiectiv models.

home.html

```
{% for obiectiv in obiective %}
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card rounded-0 shadow border-primary text-start summary-card my-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="d-flex w-100">
                        <div class="col-8 pe-2">
                            <div class="summary-title fs-5 border-bottom">Total Categories</div>
                            <div class="summary-count text-end fw-bolder mt-3 px-4">{{ obiectiv.numeObiectiv|intcomma }}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="summary-icon p-3 rounded border text-center bg-gradient bg-light">
                                <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, when we have a many-to-many relationship, Django maps the set of objects on both sides of the relationship: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

I mean, you can access the `Obiectiv.user`s and you can also access the `User.obiectiv_set` (the other side of the relation).

Then, you can rewrite your view to this:

```py
@login_required
def home(request):   
    obiective  = request.user.obiectiv_set.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', context={"obiective":obiective})
```

Hope it can help you!